# Install Shield limited edition setup (Rolling back)

Tags: installshield-le

I have just finished creating an installer using Install Shield Limited edition. My Install shield project compiles without any errors. However, when I run the setup file, after it has copied the program files into the target folder, the installer starts rolling back and deletes the installation folder.

I have not yet put any custom action or defined any pre-requsities.

Has anyone encountered such an issue?

All I am doing in the installer is following:

1. Creating directory structure under "Program files (x86)" directory using "Files" option of Install shield.
2. Creating a Website and a application underneath it using the "Internet Information Services" option.

I have attached the settings of web application and web site with this post.

Would appreciate any inputs.

> InstallShield 17:29:09: SetAspversion: machine is 64-bit and IIS running in a bit mode other than the currently selected mode
>   **InstallShield 17:29:09: Error with IISRT: -2172
>   CustomAction ISIISInstall returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
>   Action ended 17:29:09: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.**
>   MSI (s) (7C:E0) [17:29:09:312]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
>   MSI (s) (7C:E0) [17:29:09:312]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
>   MSI (s) (7C:E0) [17:29:09:319]: Executing op: Header(Signature=1397708873,Version=500,Timestamp=1113951137,LangId=1033,Platform=0,ScriptType=2,ScriptMajorVersion=21,ScriptMinorVersion=4,ScriptAttributes=1)
>   MSI (s) (7C:E0) [17:29:09:319]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=0,Argument=1033)
>   MSI (s) (7C:E0) [17:29:09:319]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=1,Argument=MyApplication)
>   MSI (s) (7C:E0) [17:29:09:319]: Executing op: RollbackInfo(,RollbackAction=Rollback,RollbackDescription=Rolling back action:,RollbackTemplate=[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TXvm.gif),CleanupAction=RollbackCleanup,CleanupDescription=Removing backup files,CleanupTemplate=File: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TXvm.gif))
>   Action 17:29:09: Rollback. Rolling back action:
>   Rollback: ISIISInstall
>   MSI (s) (7C:E0) [17:29:09:321]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=ISIISInstall,,)
>   MSI (s) (7C:E0) [17:29:09:321]: Executing op: ProductInfo(ProductKey={95199403-696F-4BF6-A443-19866156E3BD},ProductName=My Application,PackageName=My Application.msi,Language=1033,Version=16777216,Assignment=1,ObsoleteArg=0,ProductIcon=ARPPRODUCTICON.exe,,PackageCode={F3B9DBEB-71D6-42C3-B18C-1C5CCBA647E0},,,InstanceType=0,LUASetting=0,RemoteURTInstalls=0,ProductDeploymentFlags=3)
>   Rollback: Copying new files

[image: Web site]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution to the a fore-mentioned problem.

The Error with IISRT: -2172 was caused because of the setting of Application pool (app pool) in IIS.

The property named "Enable 32-Bit Applications" was set to `False`. When I changed its value to `True`, the installer was able to successfully complete the installation without rolling back.

Problem solved :)